# Getting pairs of divisors for all numbers up to certain limit

Tags: javascript, division

I am working on mechanism to get all the divisor pairs for all the numbers up to certain limit..

Result would be array that is like 'times table' but for division, also I would like to emit divisions by 1 as these are pretty obvious....

Object structure would be `{result, x, y}` e.g `[{result:4,x:2,y:2},{result:6,x:2,y:3},{result:6,x:3,y:2},...]`

To those with twitchy finger that hit downvote (and scream SHOW US THE CODE!!!) - **this is a self answer question** as I couldn't find it on SO and it will be useful for future visitors. So look in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's an answer

```js
var getAllDivisors = function(limit) {
  var array = [];
  for (var num = 2; num <= limit; num++) {
    var square_root = Math.sqrt(num);
    for (var i = 2; i <= square_root; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        var div = (num / i);
        array.push({
          result: num,
          x: i,
          y: div
        });
        if (i * i != num)
          array.push({
            result: num,
            y: i,
            x: div
          });
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```